# FORGE Viewer is frozen occasionally with long time use and cannot load models

Tags: autodesk-forge

FORGE Viewer is frozen occasionally without any pattern.
Any advice or check point will be highly appreciated.

User Environment :

- Using Chrome Browser
- Model file is dxfx format, loads 700kb sized 1 to 3 files in average

Tried :

- Removed duplicated events while multiple model load
- Removed dependencies between events
- Enabled WebGL Draft Extensions option in Chrome Browser
- Loaded Autodesk.MemoryLimited Extension

Answer (score 0):

Forge Viewer is able to display scenes with gigabytes worth of data, so a 700kB file should not be an issue, even without the `Autodesk.MemoryLimited` extension. So it could be one of the following:

- an issue with the JavaScript code loading the models
- a problem with the design file
- a problem with hardware

Try using the [profiler](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools) in Chrome Dev Tools to capture one of the "lags", and see where the CPU time is being spent. If you still can't find the issue, please consider sharing the input file and the JavaScript code you use to load the model. If you want to, you can send it to our official email alias `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we'll debug it on our end.